# JQuery conflict (Joomla)

Tags: php, jquery, joomla

Good morning,

I have created an small application inside Joomla and it's causing conflict with the rating system. That's the first lines of my custom code:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>  
<script>  
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $("#flip1").click(function(){  
        $("#panel1").slideToggle("500");  
    });  
    $("#flip2").click(function(){  
        $("#panel2").slideToggle("500");  
    });  
    $("#flip3").click(function(){  
        $("#panel3").slideToggle("500");  
    });  
});  
</script>
```

**When I put the JQuery:** the rating is not working, but my custom code it's working.

**When I delete the JQuery**: the rating is working, but my custom code it's not working.

What can I do in order to make it work? Because they can't "live" together, but they have to...!

**URL:** http://www.idermo.es/index.php?option=com_zoo&view=item&item_id=1844&Itemid=477

Thanks,

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It it most likely due to the fact that you have 2 jQuery files being imported. 1 from your code, and the other coming from Zoo.

To ensure that only 1 library is imported, use the following to import jQuery:

**Joomla 2.5**

```
<?php
  // load jQuery, if not loaded before
  if(!JFactory::getApplication()->get('jquery')){
     JFactory::getApplication()->set('jquery',true);
     $document = JFactory::getDocument();
     $document->addScript("http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js");
  }
?>
```

**Joomla 3.x**

```
JHtml::_('jquery.framework');
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Good morning Lodder. Where I have to put that code? I have a Joomla 2.5. Regards, Thanks.

Comment: You said you created an "application", so by this, I assume you mean a module or plugin. You will need to add the code inside there ;)

Comment: It's like one app (rating) is working with JQuery 1.08 and my app it's working with JQuery 1.10...! There is a toggle effect for a 1.08 JQuery version? Thanks,

Comment: I have moved the position of the JQuery and now it worked! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is most probably in a conflict with Jquery Identifier ( $ ) 
Please [read here](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) for further informations on how you can avoid that